# Cut the text in braces from txt in batch

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a lot of .txt files which has information like this:

> ```
> randomtext[IMPORTANTTEXT]morerandomtext
> ```

How can I cut out the important text without the braces and maybe overwrite the original .txt in batch?

Comment: `[`/`]` are (square) brackets, `{`/`}` are usually referred to as braces. Anyway, have you tried anything on your own? Ever heard of the [`for /F` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)?

Comment: Yes i tried a few thing, and try to find an answer but I'm not really familiar with batch. I don't understand the delimiters and how you use the loop to navigate in text

Comment: Can they have multiple "important parts" in the same line?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will also do multiple instances in the same line. I'll leave it to you to change it to use a path for the *.txt files.

Test data:

```
Test1.txt
randomtext[IMPORTANTTEXT1a]morerandomtext
randomtext[IMPORTANTTEXT1b]morerandomtext

Test2.txt
randomtext[IMPORTANTTEXT2]morerandomtext
randomtext[IMPORTANTTEXT2a]morerandomtext randomtext[IMPORTANTTEXT2b]morerandomtext
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem For each text file in the current directory...
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
    set FileSpec=%%F

    rem For each line of text in the file that has at least one [ 
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[" %%a in (!FileSpec!) do (
        rem This line of text has a [ so get the important text. %%a[%%b
        rem below passes the entire line of text.
        call :FindImportantText %%a[%%b
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
pause
exit /b

:FindImportantText
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[" %%c in ("%*") do (
    rem The "%*" above is the entire line of text even if it contains
    rem spaces which would normally delimit the line into pieces
    if not "%%d"=="" (
        rem There is a [ and text following the [. %%d is the portion
        rem following the [.

        rem so find the ending ]
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%e in ("%%d") do (
            if not "%%f"=="" (
                rem We have an ending ] so show it
                echo ImportantText in !FileSpec!=%%e

                rem Try again with the remaining portion of the line
                call :FindImportantText %%f         
            )
        )
    ) 
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

This will filter out the parts between the first pair of brackets:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('type %1') do echo.%%a>>%2
```

If there are lines without any "important parts", you can skip them with `findstr` or by checking whether the output is empty:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('type %1') do if "%%a" neq "" echo.%%a>>%2
```

---

To process all .txt files in the current directory, call the loop with another loop:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do call :brekkies "%%a" "%%~na_out.txt"&echo.%%a
echo.done.
exit /b

:brekkies
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('type %1') do if "%%a" neq "" echo.%%a>>%2
```

Files are going to be named "[name]_out.txt".